# Does tdengine supports create index on normal columns?

Tags: tdengine

I used tdengine for a few weeks, since our table have more than 30 million record for a table, however I want to filter with a nchar column. I have built a cluster with three nodes. But the filter response speed is not as fast as MySQL.I thought that if I can create index on this column the speed will be faster. Since i filtered with timestamp which is the primary key and tdengine automatically create index on this column. So I want to ask if tdengine supports create index ? If so, how to create? Can some help?

Answer (score 0):

TDengine not support create index on other columns till now.BUt it automatically create index for ts(the first column timestamp type). It will support create index on normal column in the furture.